# Is App engine ThreadManager still usable?

Tags: google-app-engine, microservices

I'm using GAE standard environment.

When calling

```
ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread({
                try {
                    doSomething()
                } catch (exception: Exception) {
                    //do nothing - logging failed
                }
            })
```

I got  the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This feature is only available to backend instances.
```

I'm using the new services (modules?), as the backend instances are documented as deprecated. So are there any methods that allows to mark an instance as a backend one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you need to define the scaling type for your module. here you can find an overview

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine

Please try to configure manual or basic scaling for your module. Only for this scaling types background thread are allowed